# How to count specific column in excel csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a csv file. It is 6 rows x 28 columns. It has a column called OS_STATUS. It has two things in the column: Live or deceased. I need a code that can only count the number of live people and their corresponding age (age is another column) and plot a graph. I need a way to only count the live people.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

cereal = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\farid-PC\\Desktop\\class\\CS7265_BIG_DATA\\sam1.csv')
print(cereal)
x =[]
x.append(df['os_status'])
```

Comment: Have you followed any pandas tutorial? How did that application work out? What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['os_status'] == "live", "age"].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on pandas Excel module, but this sounds easily doable with the xlwings module. You would just need a loop through whatever rows are being evaulated, and then you could say `if sheet.range('A{}'.format(row).value == 'Alive':`

```
`code to grab the name from same row`
```